# Discrepancy Between Apache Response Time and First Byte Time Reported By AppDynamics

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-web-services

Apache access logs shows it took 16,765 microsecond to serve a request.
AppDynamics shows that first byte time for the same request is 18,739 milliseconds.
Amazon ELB shows backend processing time = 0.017447 seconds, which is consistent with Apache.

Here are all values reported in ELB logs.
request_processing_time, backend_processing_time, response_processing_time = 0.00008, 0.017447, 0.000022

We were under the impression that Apache logs time after last byte is sent to client. May be this is wrong assumption.

This request came from Shenyang, China and our server is in Virgina, USA.
Surprisingly, AppD is reporting it as First Byte Time and not as network time.

Is it safe to assume that time reported by AppD is actually due to network delay and it is not the first byte time?

Thanks,
Sameer

Answer (score 1):

EUM first byte time is from the client's perspective, therefore it will include network latency to the server and the time to send the request to the server. Apache response time will start when the server receives the request.

Here's some more information: https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO41/Browser+RUM+Metrics